# vim how to transform text in this way

Tags: vim

I want to transform this following text in a single line from

```
[12.2,3.3 ,8.1 ,9., 12.4]
```

to

```
5
12.2
3.3
8.1
9.
12.4
```

or from

```
[def,  abc , ghi ]
```

into

```
3
def
abc
ghi
```

So, essentially, removing `[` and `]`, breaking elements based on `,` and remove leading or trailing spaces, and then put the number of elements as the first line (`5` in the first example and `3` in the second) and each element in the following lines.

How to write a command to do this fast in vim?

Comment: What did you try?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Steps**

1.Strip spaces in the list:

```
:s/ //g
```

2.Add number of elements to the start:

```
:s/\v\[(([^,]+)*[^\]]+)\]/\=len(split(submatch(1), ',')).','.submatch(1)/
```

3.Replace `,` with `\r`:

```
:s/,/\r/g
```

---

**Results**

After first step:

```
[12.2,3.3,8.1,9.,12.4]
```

After second step:

```
5,12.2,3.3,8.1,9.,12.4
```

After last step:

```
5
12.2
3.3
8.1
9.
12.4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are ok with python(installed in your os and activated in vim) you can:

1. edit the text to: 

   `a=[your list];print(len(a));
   for x in a:print(x)`
2. enter visual mode and select all the text
3. just type `:!python` and it should transform your list to the desired shape, replacing the original

**P. S.**: the string need to be quoted in order for this to work